# pandas and category replacement

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, categories

I'm trying to reduce the size of ~300 csv files (about a billion rows) by replacing lengthy fields with shorter, categorical, values.

I'm making use of pandas, and I've iterated through each of the files to build an array that includes *all* of the unique values I'm trying to replace. I can't individually just use pandas.factorize on each file, because I need (for example) '3001958145' to map to the same value on file1.csv as well as file244.csv. I've created an array of what I'd like to replace these values *with* just by creating another array of incremented integers.

```
In [1]: toreplace = data['col1'].unique()
Out[1]: array([1000339602, 1000339606, 1000339626, ..., 3001958145, 3001958397,
   3001958547], dtype=int64)

In [2]: replacewith = range(0,toreplace))
Out[2]: [0, 1, 2,...]
```

Now, how do I go about efficiently swapping in my 'replacewith' variable for each corresponding 'toreplace' value for each of the files I need to iterate through?

With as capable as pandas is with dealing with categories, I assume there *has* to be a method out there that can accomplish this that I simply just can't find. The function I wrote to do this works (it relies on a pandas.factorized input rather than the arrangement I described above), but it relies on the replace function and iterating through the series so it's quite slow.

```
def powerreplace(pdseries,factorized):
  i = 0
  uniques = pdseries.unique()
  for unique in uniques:
    print '%i/%i' % (i,len(uniques))
    i=i+1
    pdseries.replace(to_replace=unique,
                     value=np.where(factorized[1]==unique)[0][0],
                     inplace=True)
```

Can anyone recommend a better way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This requires at least pandas 0.15.0; (however the `.astype` syntax is a bit more friendly in 0.16.0, so better to use that). Here are the [docs for categoricals](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html)

Imports

```
In [101]: import pandas as pd
In [102]: import string
In [103]: import numpy as np    
In [104]: np.random.seed(1234)
In [105]: pd.set_option('max_rows',10)
```

Create a sample set to create some data

```
In [106]: uniques = np.array(list(string.ascii_letters))
In [107]: len(uniques)
Out[107]: 52
```

Create some data

```
In [109]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : uniques.take(np.random.randint(0,len(uniques)/2+5,size=1000000))})

In [110]: df1.head()
Out[110]: 
   A
0  p
1  t
2  g
3  v
4  m

In [111]: df1.A.nunique()
Out[111]: 31

In [112]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : uniques.take(np.random.randint(0,len(uniques),size=1000000))})

In [113]: df2.head()
Out[113]: 
   A
0  I
1  j
2  b
3  A
4  m
In [114]: df2.A.nunique()
Out[114]: 52
```

So we now have 2 frames that we want to categorize; the first frame happens to have less than the full set of categories. This is on purpose; you don't have to know the complete set upfront.

Convert the A columns to B columns that are a Categorical

```
In [116]: df1['B'] = df1['A'].astype('category')

In [118]: i = df1['B'].cat.categories

In [124]: i
Out[124]: Index([u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D', u'E', u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd', u'e', u'f', u'g', u'h', u'i', u'j', u'k', u'l', u'm', u'n', u'o', u'p', u'q', u'r', u's', u't', u'u', u'v', u'w', u'x', u'y', u'z'], dtype='object')
```

If we are iteratively processing these frames, we use the first ones to start. To get each successive one, we add the symmetric difference with the existing set. This keeps the categories in the same order, so when we factorize we get the same numbering scheme.

```
In [119]: cats = i.tolist() + i.sym_diff(df2['A'].astype('category').cat.categories).tolist()
```

We have now gained back the original set

```
In [120]: (np.array(sorted(cats)) == sorted(uniques)).all()
Out[120]: True
```

Set the next frames B column to be a categorical, BUT we specify the categories, so when it is factorized the same values are used

```
In [121]: df2['B'] = df2['A'].astype('category',categories=cats)
```

To prove it, we select the codes (the factorized map) from each. These codes match; df2 has an additional code (as Z is in the 2nd frame but not the first).

```
In [122]: df1[df1['B'].isin(['A','a','z','Z'])].B.cat.codes.unique()
Out[122]: array([30,  0,  5])

In [123]: df2[df2['B'].isin(['A','a','z','Z'])].B.cat.codes.unique()
Out[123]: array([ 0, 30,  5, 51])
```

You can simply then store the codes in lieu of the object dtyped data.

Note that it is actually quite efficient to serialize these to HDF5 as Categoricals are natively stored, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#categorical-data)

Note that we are creating a pretty memory efficient way of storing this data. Noting that the memory usage of in [154], the `object` dtype is actually MUCH higher the longer the string gets because this is just the memory for a pointer; the actual values are stored on the heap. While [155] is ALL the memory used.

```
In [153]: df2.dtypes
Out[153]: 
A      object
B    category
dtype: object

In [154]: df2.A.to_frame().memory_usage()
Out[154]: 
A    8000000
dtype: int64

In [155]: df2.B.to_frame().memory_usage()
Out[155]: 
B    1000416
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly well thought out response. That explanation was crystal clear, and extremely helpful! I wasn't familiar with the symmetric difference method (it's a SQL JOIN!), but I see how that will be useful in the future. I'd also completely missed the fact that the categories dtype factorizes "under the hood", and that the codes are readily accessible. The memory aspect makes perfect sense, too. Thank you for pointing it out.

I'm excited to get this approach implemented!

Answer (score 1):

First, let's create some random 'categorical' data.

```
# Create some data
random_letters = list('ABCDEFGHIJ')
s_int = pd.Series(np.random.random_integers(0, 9, 100))
s = pd.Series([random_letters[i] for i in s_int])
>>> s.unique()
array(['J', 'G', 'D', 'C', 'F', 'B', 'H', 'A', 'I', 'E'], dtype=object)
```

Now we'll create a mapping of the unique categories to integers.]

```
# Create a mapping of integers to the relevant categories.
mapping = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(s.unique())}

>>> mapping
{'A': 7,
 'B': 5,
 'C': 3,
 'D': 2,
 'E': 9,
 'F': 4,
 'G': 1,
 'H': 6,
 'I': 8,
 'J': 0}
```

Then we use list comprehension to do an inplace replacement of the categories to their mapped integers (the underscore assignment represents an unused dummy variable).

```
_ = [s.replace(cat, mapping[cat], inplace=True) for cat in mapping]

>>> s.head()
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
dtype: int64
```

If you wish to reverse the process and obtain the original categories:

```
reverse_map = {k: v for v, k in mapping.iteritems()}

reverse_map
{0: 'J',
 1: 'G',
 2: 'D',
 3: 'C',
 4: 'F',
 5: 'B',
 6: 'H',
 7: 'A',
 8: 'I',
 9: 'E'}

_ = [s.replace(int, reverse_map[int], inplace=True) for int in reverse_map]

>>> s.head()
0    J
1    G
2    D
3    C
4    F
dtype: object
```

Comment: This does work, and it works much more efficiently that my attempt, but Jeff's solution is even quicker as it relies on the built-in functionality of pandas' category dtype.

Comment: I should have mentioned that as well, but it requires Pandas 0.15+ as he mentions.