# Initilize multiple dataframe columns with categorical labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Problem statement:

I need to load 1000's csv  files into a data frame. All files have the same columns. The values in each of the columns belong to a **limited** set of possible values in all cases (different per column). The length of the values lies in the 100's of chars. I do not know beforehand those values.

My approach has been to parse each of the files and convert into a dataframe, with categorical columns and store them in hdfs store. Later concat them all together into "in memory" dataframe.

As I cannot concatenate all this dataframes due to conflicting category values, I want to create an empty dataframe, with same columns and  all category values seen in the files I processed.

The empty categorized dataframe is my starting point to concatenate one after another.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=["A","B"], dtypes={"A":"category","B":"category"} categories={"A":["a","b","c"],"B":["A","B","C","D"]})

df.concat[df1,df2,df3,d4]
```

or so I wish....

would a different strategy work better ?

Something like

Comment: I would not categorize till you complete your in-memory concat step. Basically, I would convert all CSV files to a HDF5 file, and then parse that HDF5 file, create the categories, and write it to another HDF5 file, and probably delete the original one. If there was sufficient memory space, I would simply read the files like so: `df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in files])`, create the categories, and then write it to a HDF5 file. Does this help?

Comment: It helps, thanks. Following your thinking I can create a massive HDF dataframe on disk, which is possible. Then out of that dataframe, create a new one with the categories, which will possibly fit in memory. Rather than a pd.concat, I would be doing  store.put(df, append=True). This may work. I am on fast SSDs. Writes on HDF does not work on multi process,  will take some time.Cheers.

Comment: Yeah, you should be careful to not write to HDF5 in multiple threads. And if all you are doing is reading CSV and writing, then multithreaded workflow might quite certainly result in lower performance. Do not forget to set your columns as [data columns](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#query-via-data-columns), so that you can easily hash your table one column at a time to determine category values. Take a look at the [cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#hdfstore) as well...

Comment: unfortunately this won't work. In order to be able to append, you need to use format="tables" and this is fixed lengh field. I stopped at 160Gigs...... not workable. I am thinking moving to sqlite for this intermediate step.

Comment: Use a table format. It will still be faster than SQL. (At least, I found that HDF5 tables were faster than PostgreSQL tables on the same server, with HDD storage.)

Comment: as said, space sky-rockets....with table format due to the fixed field length. I am looking at normalizing the data on a first step, creating dataframes for the different indexed fields, and then a dataframe with just the indexes to the former. Maybe I should just split the analysis. I am trying to load nearly a  billion rows and it is probably just plain stupid. My strategy is wrong.

Comment: So there is an append to multiple something in the docs. Take a look, that might be what you're looking for. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved in pandas v0.19.0, see [issue in gihub](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12699) and [in pandas docs v.1.19 dev](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#categorical-concatenation).

However, there is another  post with an excellent and detailed solution to this very same problem with a  pre v1.19 solution [pandas with category replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709918/pandas-and-category-replacement)